# Are CartoDB Map views by month or by year?

Tags: web-mapping, cartography, carto, viewer

We have 10000 map views with the free version of CartoDB.

Are they reset every month or is it the maximum views for the all utilisation ?

Answer (score 2):

I work at CartoDB! It is per month :)

http://cartodb.com/terms#map_views

Answer (score 1):

I just visited the [CartoDB Pricing](http://cartodb.com/pricing) page and I can see the ambiguous wording that has led to your question.

[image]

It also says there:

> Do you need more information? **Ask sales**

Since this is a question concerning the commercial offering of CartoDB I think you should click the **Ask sales** link on that page.

I would read it as 10,000 views in total i.e. the free trial runs out when they do.